# Salesforce Java wsdl malformed query exception in QueryResult

Tags: java, salesforce

I'm trying to get the user record from salesforce based on Email. I'm providing SQL query in request string.

Problem comes with email containing apostrophe like Prash.O'Brian@testdomain.com

That apostrophe making query as malformed, I tried replacing apostrophe in email in query string.

1. Query string: "select Id from Contact where Email = " + "\"" + email + "\""
2. replacing it to double apostrophe "''".
3. replacing it to slash and apostrophe "\'".

None of these worked!

```
public String contactSearch(String email){
     String request = String.format(
                  "select Id from Contact where Email = '%s'",
                  email
          );

final QueryResult queryResult = withTry(r -> connection().query(r), request, errMsg);

    if (!queryResult.isDone()) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(err);
    }

    return queryResult.getRecords().length == 0 ? null : queryResult.getRecords()[0].getId();
  }
```

Any suggestions please! Why salesforce giving me Malformed Query, how to handle emails with apostrophe in salesforce SQL query calls?

Comment: What's the end result string you send to the API when you escape with slash + apostrophe? `select Id from Contact where Email = 'Prash.O\'Brian@testdomain.com'` should be valid

Comment: Yes, you are right however for Java string manipulation I had to add this condition ` if (email.contains("'")){
      request = String.format(
              "select Id from Contact where Email = '%s'",
              email.replace("'", "\\'")
      );
    }` eventually string should be `select Id from Contact where Email = 'Prash.O\'Brian@testdomain.com` and this worked. With 3rd point `replacing it to slash and apostrophe "\'".` didn't work for same reason.